# How to draw a bitmap file on a canvas in html?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

How to draw a .bmp file using a canvas tag in html. i found ways to draw a png and jpeg but not bmp files. Can someone suggest me the approaches and also does every browser and platform support bmp files? Please help.

Comment: You might find this helpful: http://www.worldwidewhat.net/2012/07/how-to-draw-bitmaps-using-javascript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawing .bmp file is not limited by the canvas but infact by the browser. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support) is a link to the browser image file support list. Besides that if you are new to canvas I am going to point you [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial) to a bunch of fantastic resources on using canvas specifically the section of images about half way down the page. Out of curiosity why are you drawing and image to canvas instead of using an img tag?

Comment: its basically an app which has a blend of videos and text

Comment: what would be the role of the .bmp content?